# Questions to find number of arrangements

Tags: discussion

There are many questions in this website asking for finding number of arrangements under different constraints. All of them are similar, but sometimes different approaches are needed for these problems.

I have now answered some of them with the help of a [tool](http://www.careerbless.com/calculators/word/index.php) and added to community wiki. Some of these questions which I answered using the tool are given below. There are many such questions available
[Question 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070764/number-of-arrangements-of-the-letters-of-the-word-aaabbbccdefghi-where-as-mu)
[Question 4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1701633/arrangement-of-the-word-bfmathematics-in-which-no-two-same-letter-occur-t)

Is it good if I answer more questions using this tool by adding to community wiki because after some days, I may end up in adding many such answers because these questions are appearing very frequently.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're doing. In Question 1, you didn't answer someone's question, you posted a question and then included the answer in the body of the question. I'm not sure what that's meant to accomplish.

Comment: sorry, question 1 and 2 was a wrong examples. I was trying to verify whether this tool gives right answers. Later, using some python script I got, I found that the tool was right and then I answered some other questions using this tool. kindly see question $3,4$ (edited question)

Comment: I believe you are trying something novel in good faith, but it seems to make a point of tying solutions to the linked tool for generating exercises.  Your small sample does not demonstrate convincingly that such semi-automated posts are capable of providing the best content for Math.SE.